# Errors upgrading to the latest roscpp debs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm seeing the following errors when upgrading to the latest versions of the roscpp debs:

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

... snip ...

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-cpp-common_0.3.17-0precise-20140108-0945-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/header.h', which is also in package ros-hydro-roscpp 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-1959-+0000
```

... snip ...

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-roscpp-traits_0.3.17-0precise-20140108-0948-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/message_event.h', which is also in package ros-hydro-roscpp 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-1959-+0000
```

... snip ...

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-rosbag-storage_1.9.52-0precise-20140108-1606-+0000_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/opt/ros/hydro/include/rosbag/buffer.h', which is also in package ros-hydro-rosbag 1.9.50-0precise-20131015-2159-+0000
```

... snip ...

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-cpp-common_0.3.17-0precise-20140108-0945-+0000_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-roscpp-traits_0.3.17-0precise-20140108-0948-+0000_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/ros-hydro-rosbag-storage_1.9.52-0precise-20140108-1606-+0000_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Has anyone else seen this before? Any suggestions for dealing with these upgrade errors or working around them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/116611/errors-upgrading-to-the-latest-roscpp-debs/) by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running `sudo apt-get install -f` fixed this for me.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0